# Chrome Extension: Storing items in content script and processing in event page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome extension that processes items on a page via the content script and processes the items in the background script. It's my understanding that the background script is useful for long processing (e.g. if I have a queue of items I need to process over time).

```
// contentScript.js
function process(matches) {
    if(matches && matches.length) {
        chrome.storage.local.get({ queue: [] }, function(result) {
            var updated_queue = result.queue;
            var item = matches.pop();
            updated_queue.push(item);

            chrome.storage.local.set({ queue: updated_queue }, function() {
                process(matches);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

This works and stores each item in the local storage, which I should be able to process later. I'm not if this is the correct way to do this, but it addresses what appears to be a race condition otherwise.

I would like to process each of these items in the event page and have tried using an event listener to track changes to my local storage:

```
// eventPage.js
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function(changes, namespace) {
    // Pop the item from the local storage, process it and save the
    // updated queue back to the local storage for additional processing.
});
```

The problem is, this introduces a similar race condition I was experiencing before. As the content script adds new items to the local storage key, popping them off in the event page causes issues. There doesn't appear to be any sort of mutex or locking mechanism that I can use.

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: You can store the items separately using a new random key (e.g. 'prefix' + performance.now()) instead of using an array. Your onChanged listener will process the item and remove it from the storage immediately. On the other hand, it's not clear why you use a storage for what seems to be better solved via messaging.

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried using messaging, but it suffered from similar race condition like issues. I'd like to continue processing the items even after the user navigates away from the page. I assumed that putting things in local storage would be the correct way to do this. So you're saying that I should be able to just send a message to my event page, process it there without the need for a storage mechanism?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying.

Comment: @wOxxOm Ok, thanks! That makes sense. Guess I was just overcomplicating it!